# Why is dotted line poppinng up in excel?

Tags: excel

why is dotted line appearing in excel as in attached picture and how do i remove it ? Also is there any repo where I can refer for excel features ?

[image]

Comment: "Also is there any repo where I can refer for excel features?" - Have you searched Google (or Bing, or ...)? There are entire websites dedicated to the various features of Excel, even aside from the MSDN site(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from your image, but it looks like what you're seeing are page breaks, indicating where your sheet would generate a new page if you printed it.

That is, if you printed your sheet, columns R through Z would print on a separate page from column Q.  I suspect that there is another vertical line somewhere between columns A and Q as well.

You can ignore them; I'm not sure there's a way to get rid of them.  You can, of course, set your own print area -- on recent versions of Excel, it's under "Page Layout" and "Print Area".  You highlight the area you want to print and select "Set Print Area".  (You can also clear it, should you decide to print the entire sheet.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hm - odd.  I created a NEW workbook, and don't show any pagebreak lines like I believe OP is seeing.  However! If I change the view (click one of the other views on the bottom right, near the zoom slider), and go back to "Normal", the page breaks show with the dotted lines.  I suspect because I went to the "Page Break View", which set page breaks, and then back to Normal.  I guess when creating a new workbook, it doesn't set any by default?

Comment: Yes, I believe that once Excel computes the paging (either by printing or by going to print preview [1] or page break view), the lines show up.  Prior to that, however, it doesn't bother.  Mind you, that's only a guess, but it fits with what I've experienced.

[1] older versions had the very handy Print Preview function right there on the toolbar.  In the current version, you have to go to "Page Layout" then click the little box/arrow in the lower right corner to get the full options window, from which you can select Print Preview.

Comment: And now I know you can't have blank lines in comments so footnotes don't work.

Comment: Have done nothing but lines were gone..

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think if you shut down Excel then re-open it and re-open the file, it doesn't bother recalculating the page breaks.